# What is wrong with my AMPscript? I am looking to inject a record into a Active Journey using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am simply looking to pull the Auth token then use it to inject a record into an active Event Entry Journey. I think the issue is with the HTTPPost2 section.

**Other information:**

- The DE linked to the journey has all the fields in the @journeyBody variable, only the Contact_Key is NOT NULLABLE while the rest are.
- Date fields are date data type, Mobile is phone data type while the rest are Text.
- I am attempting to run this AMPscript in a Cloudpage.
- When I comment out the HTTPPost2 section I am able to view the token and the journeyBody variable.

**Here is my code:**

```
     %%[
        SET @body = '{"client_id": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzy","client_secret": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "grant_type": "client_credentials"}'
        SET @accessToken = HTTPPost2("https://QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token", "application/json", @body, True, @callstatus, @response)
        SET @PullaccessToken = REGEXMATCH(@callstatus,'^(?:.*"access_token":")(.*?)(?:".*)$',1)
        
    SET @journeyBody = '{
            "ContactKey": "003QQQQQQQQQQQQ",
            "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS",
            "EstablishContactKey": true,
            "Data": { "Contact_Key":"003QQQQQQQQQQQQ", 
                      "MobilePhone":"61000000007", 
                      "FirstName":"Christos", 
                      "AppointmentDate":"2022/04/11", 
                      "Case_ID":"0005ZZZZZZZZZZZ", 
                      "MessageText":"[SFMC] Hi there friend, here is your booking information: 2PM 23 Nov 2022. I hope you can attend.", 
                      "Message_Assessment":"SFMC_Y", 
                      "Inbound_or_Outbound":"Outbound", 
                      "DateAddedAEST":"2022/04/20"
                    }
           }'
        SET @bearerAccess_token = CONCAT('Bearer ', @PullaccessToken)
        
         set @postrequest = HTTPPost2("https://QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events", 'application/json', @journeyBody, True, @PullaccessToken)
        
        ]%%
        
        <br>
        access_token: %%=v(@PullaccessToken)=%% 
        <br>
        BODY: %%=v(@journeyBody)=%%
```

Comment: Why are you using AMPscript for that? It’s much easier done in SSJS: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/04/07/add-subscribers-to-a-journey-from-a-cloudpage-using-fire-entry-event/

Comment: You didnt add the header name 'Authorization' as a parameter in the second HttpPost2, according to the documentation in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/httppost2.html

Comment: Hi guys 
Thanks for showing interest in my post! 

zuzannamj, I am planning on testing this ampscript in an SMS message. From my understanding, SSJS wont work in an SMS message? 

@SebOB, thanks! I took your advice and it now works :D

Answer (score 0):

Changing the HTTPPost2 to this has it working:

```
 set @postrequest = HTTPPost2("https://QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events", 'application/json', @journeyBody, True, @output,@respheader, "Authorization", @bearerAccess_token)
```